# On first time query1.addevent listener not getting called

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have to develop a chat app in android using firebase,It consist of different groups having options of leaving and joining the group,First time it doesn't show joined and leaved groups but on second time when we scroll list view or change view then it shows correctly.I have to fix the issue kindly look the below code and show what problems should be fixed.

```
public class Allgroups extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
    private List<ImageUpload> imgList;
    private List<groupuserstoken> imgList1;
    ListView listView;
    private ImageListAdapter adapter;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_allgroups);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait loading groups...");

        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.allgroups11);
        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        imgList=new ArrayList<>();
        final Query query = mDatabaseRef.child("Groups");
        listView.smoothScrollByOffset(10);
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    ImageUpload img = snapshot.getValue(ImageUpload.class);
                    imgList.add(img);
                }

                adapter = new ImageListAdapter(Allgroups.this, R.layout.custommenu, imgList);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String name=imgList.get(i).getName();
                String path=imgList.get(i).getUrl();
                String topic=imgList.get(i).getTopic();
                Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main4Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("name",name);
                intent.putExtra("path",path);
                intent.putExtra("topic",topic);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}




 public class ImageListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ImageUpload> {
        private Activity context;
        private int resource;
        private List<ImageUpload> listImage;

        private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
        private List<groupuserstoken> imgList1;
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        int pos;




        public ImageListAdapter(@NonNull Activity context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull List<ImageUpload> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            this.context = context;
            this.resource = resource;
            listImage = objects;
        }


             TextView tvName;
               TextView tvDes;
            TextView statuss;
             Button leave;
             ImageView img;





        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, @Nullable  View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

            View v = convertView;

            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi;
                vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.custommenu, null);
            }
          //  final LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
         //   v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custommenu, parent, false);

            ImageUpload listImage1 = getItem(position);

            if (listImage1 !=null) {


                tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.as);
                tvDes = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.aa);
                statuss = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.users);
                img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.addgroup1);
                leave = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.leavegroup);

                mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                final String name = listImage.get(pos).getName();
                final Query query1 = mDatabaseRef.child(name + "user");
                query1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        imgList1 = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            groupuserstoken img = snapshot.getValue(groupuserstoken.class);
                            imgList1.add(img);
                        }
                        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
                        if (!(imgList1.isEmpty())) {

                            if (!(imgList1.contains(token))) {
                                leave.setText("Leave Group");
                            }
                        }


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {


                    }
                });

                tvName.setText(listImage1.getName());
                tvDes.setText(listImage1.getDescription());
                statuss.setText(listImage1.getMembers() + " Users ");
                Glide.with(context).load(listImage1.getUrl()).into(img);
            }


            leave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String groupname = listImage.get(position).getName();
                    mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(groupname+"user").child(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
                    mDatabaseRef.child("token").setValue(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
                }
            });
            return v;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `setTag()` and `getTag()` in your adapter, but for better practice is to use `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`.